# using out.println in jsp method

Tags: jsp

This is my jsp method. In this I want to use out.println, but eclipse is showing an error can not resolve out. I have read that out is implicitly available to jsp methods. Then why it is not working?

```
public void getTest(HttpSession session)
    {
        String username = (String)session.getAttribute("email");
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     //creating connection with the database 
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
                       ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizilla","root","manish123");
        String query="select test_name, number, max_marks from test_table where email='"+username+"'";
        PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String test_name = rs.getString("test_name");
            int number= rs.getInt("number");
            int max_marks=rs.getInt("max_marks");
            String div="<div style='height:8%;width:74.8%;float:right; border:1px solid #000000'>";
            out.println(div);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
    }
```

Comment: JSP implicit objects are objects which are predefined for `_jspService()` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your method using jsp declaration, it doesn't have the access to the `out`variable which is available to the `_jspservice()` method only. You cannot use it inside any other method, unless you pass it on to the method as following.

`public void getTest(HttpSession session, OutputStream out)`